# What kind of passage I may use this Key and What's the name of this Key?

Tags: flute

I'm a flute player and I bought this flute sometime ago and I'd like to know:

**Flute Yamaha 371 Allegro version**

> What kind of passage I may use this Key and What's the name of this
>   Key?

Please, I'd like the references or a comment of a recognized flute player or some article with the example.

**Edited:**

I found the name of the key the the manufacturer's website. They call it the Ice lever (A#).

[Reference from Yamaha](https://www.yamaha.com/en/musical_instrument_guide/flute/mechanism/)

[image]

**Can you give me an example of how the Ice lever is used in practice?**

I'm accustomed to using alternative keys depending the passages on the music sheet, but this key doesn't make sense because B flat is very near to this key.

The key:

[image]

The hole that key close:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an alternative B-flat key.  It's particularly useful in chromatic combinations e.g. B B♭ A B♭, in chromatic scales, or for trills e.g. A♭ to B♭. Or for this kind of chromatic phrase
[image]

There are two advantages of using this key rather than than the F key ("long B♭"):

- There are two springs less to overcome pressing the key down, so it's faster and less noisy
- The key can be left down in passages that go down to A, A♭ or G and back

The [Woodwind Fingering Guide](https://www.wfg.woodwind.org/flute/fl_fing.html) calls this the 
"Bb trill key". [Others](http://www.tammyevansyonce.com/2011/07/23/b-flat-options/) call it the "B-flat lever". [Yamaha](https://www.yamaha.com/en/musical_instrument_guide/flute/mechanism/) calls it the "Ice lever" (possibly from the German word "Ais" for A#, pronounced "ice").

Blogger Jennifer Cluff has a series of articles on using the three different B-flat alternatives: [part 1](http://jennifercluff.blogspot.com/2012/08/why-work-on-standard-b-flat-fingering.html), [part 2](http://jennifercluff.blogspot.com/2013/06/dear-flute-lovers-discussion-has-come.html), [more](http://jennifercluff.blogspot.com/2017/11/more-free-sequences-b-flat-fingerings.html).

Comment: @Elizeu "Ice lever" is a term I've never heard before

Comment: Me neither, for this purpose I was asking.

Comment: your anwser is right. I did some tests and it make sense.

Comment: @Elizeu: "Ice lever" sounds very strange. However the word "ice" sounds just the same as "ais", the German name for A sharp... Maybe it comes from that?

Comment: @Ramillies Yes, I think one of the instrument makers at Yamaha must have studied in Germany.

Comment: It should be perhaps pointed out that the advantage of the "ice" (or "Ais") lever over just using the first finger key of the right hand is that there's one less spring to overcome pressing it down.  It's thus faster and less noisy.

Comment: @ScottWallace I thought that was obvious, but I've now mentioned it explicitly.